# How to correctly call on classes

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, attributes

I'm supposed to call on 2 different classes that then run the program so that the menu appears and the user chooses an option.  I have most of the program running, but cannot check if anything is working because I keep getting the error that `animal_type` and `name` are not defined and am having trouble figuring out why. I've attached parts of each program.

Main file:

```
import Animal
import Zoo

def main():
    #set user choice 
    animal = Animal.Animal()
```

Zoo.py:

```
import Animal

class Zoo:

    #initialize attribute
    def __init__(Animal):
        Animal.__animals = []

    def add_animal(Animal, animals):
        Animal.__animals.append(animal)

    def show_animals(Animal):
        size = len(animals)
        if size == 0:
            print("There are no animals in your zoo!")
        else:
            return __animals
```

Animal.py:

```
import random

class Animal:

    #initialize attributes
    def __init__(self,animal_type, name, mood = None):
        self.__animal_type = animal_type
        self.__name = name
        if mood:
            self.__mood = mood
        else:
            self.check_mood()

    # set methods
    def set_animal_type(self, animal_type):
        self.__animal_type = animal_type

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def set_mood(self, mood):
        self.__mood = mood
```

Comment: What do you mean by "call on"?

Comment: I'm trying to use the Animal class in the first part of the program and it wont let me becuase it apparently is missing "animal_type" and "name"

Comment: You should be creating your animal instances with something like: `animal = Animal.Animal(animal_type='lion', name='Jessie')`. Also, is there any specific reason why you're using __double __underscores before all instance variables?

Comment: For one, your indentation is off; those functions aren't being defined as methods of the classes. I'm not sure if that's just a copy/paste error or if that code would actually run (perhaps the comments under the `class` lines are sufficient to not immediately cause a syntax error?)

Answer (score 0):

In your `main` function, you aren't passing any of the required variables to `Animal`. (`animal_type` and `animal`)

You need to define them or just directly call with them.

```
animal = Animal.Animal('Goat', 'Billy')
```

or

```
atype = 'Goat'
aname = 'Billy'
animal = Animal.Animal(atype, aname)
```